# Custom areas using color palette

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout

I'm working on SharePoint 2013 and I have a problem with color palettes. I know how to create new palette, how to change colors and how to assign it to a site. This is easy as it should be.
I have my own master page, depedning on color palettes. It is modified seatle.master. Let's say that I want (just for example) create a small 10px x 10px div square, that has the same color as Suite bar background. And I don't know how do it.
I assume, that some translation happens when creating corev15.css, but I can't find anywhere this file before color applying.
Personally I think this should be as easy as applying classes to tags. Colors defined in palette and then using them as classes. I don't know why this became more complicated.
Probably there are is some magic markup that can be used in css, but I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Late already but hope it may help others in the future. In Benjamin Niaulin's [post](http://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/step-by-step-create-a-sharepoint-2013-composed-look/), kindly see the section **Using the names provided in the spcolor file in your CSS**.